# Trigger Change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

the event trigger seems to be not working.
Here is my code:

```
  {% for DepartureDate, LfidElement in Flight%}

                var DepartureDateCurrentVol = "{{DepartureDate}}";
                var weekDayRange=new Date(DepartureDateCurrentVol).getDay();
                weekDayName=returnWeekDayName(weekDayRange);
                {% for LFID, VarTypeElement in LfidElement %}
                    {% for VarTypeID, FareInfosElement in VarTypeElement %}
                        {% for FareId,FareInfo in FareInfosElement.FareInfos %}

                            var flagMin = "{{ FareInfo.FlagMinAmt|e }}";
                            var amountCurrentVol="{{ FareInfo.BaseFareAmtInclTax|e }}";
                            var fareIdDeparture="{{FareId}}";
                            if(DepartureDateCurrentVol ==  dateDepartureRequest)
                            {
                              moinsCherArrivalSelected=0;
                              montantGlobal+=parseFloat(amountCurrentVol);
                              dateDepartureRequestedFound=1;
                              $('#aller').append('<div class="v2_blocselectionorange"><div class="v2_blocselectionorangehaut">'+weekDayName+'<br />'+DepartureDateCurrentVol+'</div><div class="v2_blocselectionorangebas">à partir de <br /><span class="v2_prixselection">'+amountCurrentVol+' dt</span><div class="v2_prixselectionradio"><input type="radio" id="selectionr'+fareIdDeparture+'" name="selectionr" value="1" checked="checked"></div></div></div>');
                              volSelected['Departure']=fareIdDeparture;
                              $('#retour').empty();
                              //$("#selectionr"+fareIdDeparture).change();
                              $("#selectionr"+fareIdDeparture).trigger("change");
                            }
$("#selectionr"+fareIdDeparture).change(function(){
                          var idFareIDCurrent=$(this).attr('id').substring(10);
                          FareInfo=idFareIDCurrent;
                         {% for key,pas in FareInfo.ReturnFlightSegmentDetails%}
                              var  arrivalDate="{{key}}";
                              var weekArrivalDayRange=new Date(arrivalDate).getDay();
                              weekArrivalDayName=returnWeekDayName(weekArrivalDayRange);
                              {% for key2,ReturnFlightSegmentDetailsInfosValue in pas %}
                                  {% for key3,ReturnFlightSegmentTypeInfo in ReturnFlightSegmentDetailsInfosValue %}
                                      {% for key4,ReturnFlightSegmentInfo in ReturnFlightSegmentTypeInfo %}
                                         var amountArrivalDate="{{ ReturnFlightSegmentInfo.BaseFareAmtInclTax|e }}";
                                         var flagArrivalMin="{{ ReturnFlightSegmentInfo.FlagMinAmt|e }}";
                                         //console.info(arrivalDate);console.info(arrivalDate == dateArrivalRequest);
                                         if( arrivalDate == dateArrivalRequest)
                                         {
                                            montantGlobal+=parseFloat(amountArrivalDate);
                                            volSelected['Arrival']="{{key4}}";
                                            $('#retour').append('<div class="v2_blocselectionorange"><div class="v2_blocselectionorangehaut">'+weekArrivalDayName+'<br />'+arrivalDate+'</div><div class="v2_blocselectionorangebasblanc">à partir de <br /><span class="v2_prixselection">'+amountArrivalDate+' dt</span><div class="v2_prixselectionradio"><input type="radio" id="selectionRetour'+"{{key4}}"+'" name="selectionRetour" value="1" checked="checked"></div></div></div>');
                                            dateArrivalRequestedFound =1;

                                         }else {
                                           if(flagArrivalMin =! 1){
                                                   $('#retour').append('');
                                                 }else {
                                                      $('#retour').append('<div class="v2_blocselection"><div class="v2_blocselectionhaut">'+weekArrivalDayName+'<br />'+arrivalDate+'</div><div class="v2_blocselectionbasjaune">à partir de <br /><span class="v2_prixselection">'+amountArrivalDate+' dt</span><div class="v2_prixselectionradio"><input type="radio" name="selectionRetour" id="selectionRetour'+"{{key4}}"+'" value="1"></div></div></div>');
                                                      if(dateArrivalRequestedFound==0 && moinsCherArrivalSelected==0){
                                                         $('input[type=radio][name=selectionRetour]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                                                         moinsCherArrivalSelected=1;
                                                         montantGlobal+=parseFloat(amountArrivalDate);
                                                      }
                                                 }

                                           }
                                      {% endfor %}
                                  {% endfor %}
                              {% endfor%}
                          {% endfor %}

                       });


    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
```

can anybobody tell me how to force the exécution of the event Change?! i want to declare my function change in a first step then i will execute it each time i have a change, in fact on the loading of my page the change must be executed then if the user click to another radio button the change will be re-executed. am i doing the right alternative?

Comment: What kind of syntax is the {% .... %}? I've never seen that before

Comment: it's a twig template ^^ i'm working on symfony2